# Passing image from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a camera application where I want an image to be captured and displayed to another `Activity`.

Here is the code-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button photoclick= (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickphoto);
        Button recordgetter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.getrecord);
        Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "insomnia.ttf");
        photoclick.setTypeface(font);
        recordgetter.setTypeface(font);
        photoclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            Intent i=new Intent(this,Description.class);
            i.putExtra("BitmapImage", imageBitmap);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second class where I want the image to be displayed-

```
public class Description extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView capturedimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

        capturedimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
        capturedimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML code of second activity-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost.Description">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/capturedImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The application is forced stop as soon as I click the picture and press the tick mark. Please help.

```
00:22:33.615 19175-19175/com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost, PID: 19175
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost/com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost.Description}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost.Description.onCreate(Description.java:24)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: "The application is forced stop" When your app crashes, it is usually caused by an uncaught exception. In order to help you diagnose the problem, we need the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make you `Description` class like

```
public class Description extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView capturedimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        capturedimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedImage);
        capturedimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

You can't call `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`. That's a crash for sure. Post logcat if it's something else